# get all items that have match with other array

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I'm creating a query but i came a section when i don't have idea that how do it. I have one array that have for example two items

```
//filter array
const filterArray=r.expr(['parking', 'pool'])
```

and also i have one table with follows records:

```
[
    {
        "properties": {
            "facilities": [
                "parking"
            ],
            "name": "Suba"
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "facilities": [
                "parking",
                "pool",
                "pet friendly"
            ],
            "name": "Kennedy",
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "facilities": [
                "parking",
                "pool"
            ],
            "name": "Soacha"
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "facilities": [
                "parking",
                "pet friendly",
                "GYM"
            ],
            "name": "Sta Librada"
        }
    },
]
```

I need filter the records with the array but i need that record has all items of array filter. If the record has more item of array filter not is problem, i need if contains all items of array filter get that record. On this case I need all records that have the facilities "pool" and "parking"

#### Current query

Current query but it also return records with one or two items of the filter array

```
r.db('aucroom').table('hosts')
.filter(host=>
    host('properties')('facilities').contains(val=>{
        return filterArray.contains(val2=>val2.eq(val))

    })
)
.orderBy('properties')
.pluck(['properties'])
```

#### results that I desire wait

Like the image example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a strict match of two arrays (same number of elements, same order), then use [`.eq()`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/eq)

```
array1.eq(array2)
```

If you want the first array to contain all elements of the second array, then use [`.setIntersection()`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/set_intersection/), just note array2 should contain distinct elements (a set):

```
array1.setIntersection(array2).eq(array2)
```